# API of a package in python. In __init__.py?

Tags: python

I have written a python package which consists of several `.py` files which contain classes and so on. I want to expose it to client using "Facade" pattern. So I don't want clients to learn all internal classes but only methods exposed by this API interface.

Question is: where do I put this api ? Do I define a file `api.py` inside the package or can I put this api in the `__init__.py` of the package?

I explain better with an example

```
<my_module>\
     __init__.py
     core.py
     submodule1.py
     submodule2.py
     util.py
     ........
```

so where do I put the public API of  ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most common choice is to use `__init__.py` -- it's worth hiving off to a module of its own (or more) only if it's complex enough to warrant it (then it wouldn't be much of a Facade;-) or, more importantly, if you provide alternative APIs (a simplified one with reduced functionality but greater ease of use, and a rich/complex one, for example), in which case using separate modules keeps things better organized.

To communicate to package users that they're *not* supposed to import other modules directly, be sure to name your "private, internal implementation modules" with a *leading underscore*: `_core.py`, not `core.py`, and so forth.  This convention is always used in Python to separate public APIs from internal implementation details and is well worth the (really small) effort for you to implement it!

Comment: Would you have an example of it? I have a doubt about how doing it. E.g: just importing on __init__ the public API for the matter of exposure?

Answer (score 8):

The `__init__.py` file is an acceptable place to put the public API or a package, with the other modules within it providing the implementation.

Answer (score 7):

There are **disadvantages** to putting the api into `__init__.py`:

- there is danger of causing cycling dependencies
- it is not a obvious place to look when browsing a code base

Putting the api in a dedicated module like api.py elevates these issues. 
Furthermore, there are **advantages** like:

- you can offer another api later in a second module (simplified, different use case etc.)
- big Python projects like Enthought [traits.api](http://code.enthought.com/projects/files/ets_api/enthought.traits.api.html) and Trac [trac.api](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/trac/ticket/api.py) use this pattern